# Conflicting Seafile and Nextcloud nginx configs

Tags: php, nginx, proxypass, nextcloud

I've searched for this problem, but haven't get solution yet.
I have **Nextcloud** installed on `https://example.com/nextcloud`.
Yesterday I installed **Seafile**, that works on `https://example.com` (I simply don't know, how to make it accessible from, for example, `https://example.com/seafile`) 
While I was setting it, **Nextcloud** was switched off by deleting link to corresponding file in `sites-enabled` directory. **Seafile** worked. But when I enabled **Nextcloud**, I got error `403 forbidden` trying to access **Seafile**. I also enabled `info` level in Nginx and there I got next message:

```
2019/12/08 12:00:24 [error] 5885#5885: *109 directory index of "/var/www/" is forbidden, client: 1.2.3.4, server: 192.168.1.134, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", host: "mydomain.com"
```

I know, that problem is in config file of Nextcloud, but I can not recognize where. I post both config files.

**nextcloud.conf:**

```
upstream php-handler {
    #server 127.0.0.1:9000;
    server unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name 192.168.1.134;
    # enforce https
    return 301 https://$server_name:443$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name 192.168.1.134;

    # Use Mozilla's guidelines for SSL/TLS settings
    # https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/
    # NOTE: some settings below might be redundant
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    # Add headers to serve security related headers
    # Before enabling Strict-Transport-Security headers please read into this
    # topic first.
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload;";
    #
    # WARNING: Only add the preload option once you read about
    # the consequences in https://hstspreload.org/. This option
    # will add the domain to a hardcoded list that is shipped
    # in all major browsers and getting removed from this list
    # could take several months.
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
    add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
    add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;
    add_header Referrer-Policy no-referrer;

    # Remove X-Powered-By, which is an information leak
    fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;

    # Path to the root of your installation
    root /var/www;

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    # The following 2 rules are only needed for the user_webfinger app.
    # Uncomment it if you're planning to use this app.
    #rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /nextcloud/public.php?service=host-meta last;
    #rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /nextcloud/public.php?service=host-meta-json last;

    # The following rule is only needed for the Social app.
    # Uncomment it if you're planning to use this app.
    #rewrite ^/.well-known/webfinger /nextcloud/public.php?service=webfinger last


    location = /.well-known/carddav {
      return 301 $scheme://$host:$server_port/nextcloud/remote.php/dav;
    }
    location = /.well-known/caldav {
      return 301 $scheme://$host:$server_port/nextcloud/remote.php/dav;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge { }

    location ^~ /nextcloud {
        # set max upload size
        client_max_body_size 512M;
        fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

        # Enable gzip but do not remove ETag headers
        gzip on;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_comp_level 4;
        gzip_min_length 256;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private no_last_modified no_etag auth;
        gzip_types application/atom+xml application/javascript application/json application/ld+json application/manifest+json application/rss+xml application/vnd.geo+json application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf application/x-web-app-manifest+json application/xhtml+xml application/xml font/opentype image/bmp image/svg+xml image/x-icon text/cache-manifest text/css text/plain text/vcard text/vnd.rim.location.xloc text/vtt text/x-component text/x-cross-domain-policy;

        # Uncomment if your server is build with the ngx_pagespeed module
        # This module is currently not supported.
        #pagespeed off;

        location /nextcloud {
            rewrite ^ /nextcloud/index.php;
        }

        location ~ ^\/nextcloud\/(?:build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates|data)\/ {
            deny all;
        }
        location ~ ^\/nextcloud\/(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console) {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^\/nextcloud\/(?:index|remote|public|cron|core\/ajax\/update|status|ocs\/v[12]|updater\/.+|oc[ms]-provider\/.+)\.php(?:$|\/) {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(\/.*|)$;
            set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
            try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
            fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
            # Avoid sending the security headers twice
            fastcgi_param modHeadersAvailable true;
            # Enable pretty urls
            fastcgi_param front_controller_active true;
            fastcgi_pass php-handler;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_request_buffering off;
        }

        location ~ ^\/nextcloud\/(?:updater|oc[ms]-provider)(?:$|\/) {
            try_files $uri/ =404;
            index index.php;
        }

        # Adding the cache control header for js, css and map files
        # Make sure it is BELOW the PHP block
        location ~ ^\/nextcloud\/.+[^\/]\.(?:css|js|woff2?|svg|gif|map)$ {
            try_files $uri /nextcloud/index.php$request_uri;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=15778463";
            # Add headers to serve security related headers  (It is intended
            # to have those duplicated to the ones above)
            # Before enabling Strict-Transport-Security headers please read
            # into this topic first.
            #add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload;";
            #
            # WARNING: Only add the preload option once you read about
            # the consequences in https://hstspreload.org/. This option
            # will add the domain to a hardcoded list that is shipped
            # in all major browsers and getting removed from this list
            # could take several months.
            add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
            add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
            add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
            add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
            add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;
            add_header Referrer-Policy no-referrer;

            # Optional: Don't log access to assets
            access_log off;
        }

        location ~ ^\/nextcloud\/.+[^\/]\.(?:png|html|ttf|ico|jpg|jpeg|bcmap)$ {
            try_files $uri /nextcloud/index.php$request_uri;
            # Optional: Don't log access to other assets
            access_log off;
        }
    }
}
```

**seafile.conf:**

```
log_format seafileformat '$http_x_forwarded_for $remote_addr [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" $upstream_response_time';
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 192.168.1.134;
    rewrite ^ https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;    # force redirect http to https
    server_tokens off;
    }
    #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;        # path to your cacert.pem
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;  # path to your privkey.pem
    server_name 192.168.1.134;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:5m;
        # Diffie-Hellman parameter for DHE ciphersuites, recommended 2048 bits
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;
    # secure settings (A+ at SSL Labs ssltest at time of writing)
        # see https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Nginx
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS';
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
        server_tokens off;
        location / {
        # ......
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/seahub.access.log;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/seahub.error.log;
        proxy_read_timeout  1200s;
        client_max_body_size 0;
        }

    location /seafhttp {
        rewrite ^/seafhttp(.*)$ $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
        client_max_body_size 0;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_request_buffering off;
        proxy_connect_timeout  36000s;
        proxy_read_timeout  36000s;
        proxy_send_timeout  36000s;
        send_timeout  36000s;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/seafhttp.access.log seafileformat;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/seafhttp.error.log;
    }
    location /media {
        root /mnt/sys/haiwen/seafile-server-latest/seahub;
    }
```

}

Comment: You can't run them both in parallel, both servers are on the same IP and listen on ports 80 and 443... they will conflict

Comment: I have had same thought and nginx reported about conflict you mentioned. But how can I bypass this problem? Any ideas?

Comment: One of the servers must operate on different ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said [Lars Stegelitz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2443226/lars-stegelitz), I have to run these services on different ports. I did that and now Nextcloud runs on 445 port, at the same time Seafile on 443. I've added location `/nextcloud` and there is directive `proxy_pass https://192.168.1.134:445`;
Here are my updated configs.
**seafile.conf:**

```
log_format seafileformat '$http_x_forwarded_for $remote_addr [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" $upstream_response_time';
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 192.168.1.134;
    rewrite ^ https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;    # force redirect http to https
    server_tokens off;
    }
    #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    server {
    #root /var/www/html;
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;        # path to your cacert.pem
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;  # path to your privkey.pem
    server_name 192.168.1.134;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:5m;
        # Diffie-Hellman parameter for DHE ciphersuites, recommended 2048 bits
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;
    # secure settings (A+ at SSL Labs ssltest at time of writing)
        # see https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Nginx
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS';
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
        server_tokens off;
        location / {
        # ......
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/seahub.access.log;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/seahub.error.log;
        proxy_read_timeout  1200s;
        client_max_body_size 0;
        }
        location /nextcloud {

        proxy_pass    https://192.168.1.134:445;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
#                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;      
    }   client_max_body_size 0;

            location /transmission {

                proxy_pass    http://192.168.1.134:9091;
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
#                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
                client_max_body_size 0;

            }
    location /seafhttp {
        rewrite ^/seafhttp(.*)$ $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
        client_max_body_size 0;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_request_buffering off;
        proxy_connect_timeout  36000s;
        proxy_read_timeout  36000s;
        proxy_send_timeout  36000s;
        send_timeout  36000s;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/seafhttp.access.log seafileformat;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/seafhttp.error.log;
    }
    location /media {
        root /mnt/sys/haiwen/seafile-server-latest/seahub;
    }
}
```

**nextcloud.conf:**

```
upstream php-handler {
    #server 127.0.0.1:9000;
    server unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
}

server {
    listen 81;
    listen [::]:81;
    server_name 192.168.1.134;
    # enforce https
    return 301 https://$server_name:443$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 445 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:445 ssl http2;
    server_name 192.168.1.134;

    # Use Mozilla's guidelines for SSL/TLS settings
    # https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/
    # NOTE: some settings below might be redundant
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    # Add headers to serve security related headers
    # Before enabling Strict-Transport-Security headers please read into this
    # topic first.
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload;";
    #
    # WARNING: Only add the preload option once you read about
    # the consequences in https://hstspreload.org/. This option
    # will add the domain to a hardcoded list that is shipped
    # in all major browsers and getting removed from this list
    # could take several months.
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
    add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
    add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;
    add_header Referrer-Policy no-referrer;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";

    # Remove X-Powered-By, which is an information leak
    fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;

    # Path to the root of your installation
    root /var/www;

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    # The following 2 rules are only needed for the user_webfinger app.
    # Uncomment it if you're planning to use this app.
    #rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /nextcloud/public.php?service=host-meta last;
    #rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /nextcloud/public.php?service=host-meta-json last;

    # The following rule is only needed for the Social app.
    # Uncomment it if you're planning to use this app.
    #rewrite ^/.well-known/webfinger /nextcloud/public.php?service=webfinger last


    location = /.well-known/carddav {
      return 301 $scheme://$host:$server_port/nextcloud/remote.php/dav;
    }
    location = /.well-known/caldav {
      return 301 $scheme://$host:$server_port/nextcloud/remote.php/dav;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge { }

    location ^~ /nextcloud {
#   root /var/www;
        # set max upload size
        client_max_body_size 512M;
        fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

        # Enable gzip but do not remove ETag headers
        gzip on;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_comp_level 4;
        gzip_min_length 256;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private no_last_modified no_etag auth;
        gzip_types application/atom+xml application/javascript application/json application/ld+json application/manifest+json application/rss+xml application/vnd.geo+json application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf application/x-web-app-manifest+json application/xhtml+xml application/xml font/opentype image/bmp image/svg+xml image/x-icon text/cache-manifest text/css text/plain text/vcard text/vnd.rim.location.xloc text/vtt text/x-component text/x-cross-domain-policy;

        # Uncomment if your server is build with the ngx_pagespeed module
        # This module is currently not supported.
        #pagespeed off;

        location /nextcloud {
            rewrite ^ /nextcloud/index.php;
        }

        location ~ ^\/nextcloud\/(?:build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates|data)\/ {
            deny all;
        }
        location ~ ^\/nextcloud\/(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console) {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^\/nextcloud\/(?:index|remote|public|cron|core\/ajax\/update|status|ocs\/v[12]|updater\/.+|oc[ms]-provider\/.+)\.php(?:$|\/) {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(\/.*|)$;
            set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
            try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
            fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
            # Avoid sending the security headers twice
            fastcgi_param modHeadersAvailable true;
            # Enable pretty urls
            fastcgi_param front_controller_active true;
            fastcgi_pass php-handler;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_request_buffering off;
        }

        location ~ ^\/nextcloud\/(?:updater|oc[ms]-provider)(?:$|\/) {
            try_files $uri/ =404;
            index index.php;
        }

        # Adding the cache control header for js, css and map files
        # Make sure it is BELOW the PHP block
        location ~ ^\/nextcloud\/.+[^\/]\.(?:css|js|woff2?|svg|gif|map)$ {
            try_files $uri /nextcloud/index.php$request_uri;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=15778463";
            # Add headers to serve security related headers  (It is intended
            # to have those duplicated to the ones above)
            # Before enabling Strict-Transport-Security headers please read
            # into this topic first.
            #add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload;";
            #
            # WARNING: Only add the preload option once you read about
            # the consequences in https://hstspreload.org/. This option
            # will add the domain to a hardcoded list that is shipped
            # in all major browsers and getting removed from this list
            # could take several months.
            add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
            add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
            add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
            add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
            add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;
            add_header Referrer-Policy no-referrer;

            # Optional: Don't log access to assets
            access_log off;
        }

        location ~ ^\/nextcloud\/.+[^\/]\.(?:png|html|ttf|ico|jpg|jpeg|bcmap)$ {
            try_files $uri /nextcloud/index.php$request_uri;
            # Optional: Don't log access to other assets
            access_log off;
        }
    }
}
```